# Finding all integer numbers $a$,$b$ which satisfy $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=(4n+2)\sqrt{(4n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

Find all integer numbers $a$,$b$ which satisfy $$\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=(4n+2)\sqrt{(4n+2)}$$
when $n=0,1,2,3....$

The above equation means $$\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=2\sqrt{2}$$ $$\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=6\sqrt{6}$$ $$\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=10\sqrt{10}$$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a^2-b^2 = (4n+2)^3 \implies (a+b)(a-b) = 8(2n+1)^3$. Since $a+b$ and $a-b$ are of the same parity, let us set
$$a+b = 4(2n+1)^2 \text{ and }a-b = 2(2n+1)$$
This gives us one solution to be
$$a = 2(2n+1)^2 + (2n+1) \text{ and }b=2(2n+1)^2-(2n+1)$$
You can try to exhaust other cases.